# I am not able to understand the concept how string is converted to integers

Tags: c++, string, integer

I referred a program for time conversion and not able to understand some part of the code. Here's the full program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;

    int n = s.length();
    int hh, mm, ss;
    hh = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + (s[1] - '0');
    mm = (s[3] - '0') * 10 + (s[4] - '0');
    ss = (s[6] - '0') * 10 + (s[7] - '0');

    if (hh < 12 && s[8] == 'P') hh += 12;
    if (hh == 12 && s[8] == 'A') hh = 0;

    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hh, mm, ss);

    return 0;
}
```

The part of code i am not able to understand is

```
    hh = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + (s[1] - '0');
    mm = (s[3] - '0') * 10 + (s[4] - '0');
    ss = (s[6] - '0') * 10 + (s[7] - '0');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those aren't strings, they're `char`

Comment: This will help, see [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) `- '0'` converts a digit from it's ASCII *character* value to its actual decimal *numeric* value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see e.g. [this ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) (ASCII being the most common character encoding scheme) you can see that the *character* `'2'` has the decimal value `50`, and that the character `'0'` has the decimal value `48`.

Considering that a character is just really a small integer, we can use normal arithmetic on them. That means if you do e.g. `'2' - '0'` that's the same as doing `50 - 48` which results in the decimal value `2`.

So to get the decimal value of a character digit, just subtract `'0'`.

The multiplication with `10` is because we're dealing with the *decimal* system, where a number such as `21` is the same as `2 * 10 + 1`.

---

It should be noted that the C++ specification explicitly says that all digits have to be encoded in a contiguous range, so it doesn't matter which encoding is used this will always work.

You might see this "trick" being used to get a decimal value for letters as well, but note that the C++ specification doesn't say anything about that. In fact there are encodings where the range of letters is *not* contiguous and where this will not work. It's only specified to work on digits.

Answer (score 2):

In [the ASCCI encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) numbers are encoded sequentially. This is:

`'0'` has the value `48`

`'1'` has the value `49`

`'2'` has the value `50`

etc

Therefor, `'x' - '0' == x` from `'0'` to `'9'`

For example:

if you have your string `12:23:53` we have:

```
hh = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + (s[1] - '0');
```

`(s[0] - '0')`  means `'1'-'0'` which is equal to `1`, but this is the ten, so `*10` + `(s[1] - '0')` which is `'2'-'0'`, so 2. In total `12`.

Same thing for the minutes and seconds.